# Селениум питон получение элемента

Tags: python, html, алгоритм, классы, selenium

[image: пример]

использую селениум с питоном. при поиске элементов по классу 'line__champ' у меня в список добавляются так же скрытые элементы hidden, как мне искать через find_elements, чтобы у меня был список только открытых элементов?

Answer (score 0):

вероятно вам нужен **not contains**, если используете xpath1

см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640746/xpath-syntax-for-and-not-contains

update:
на http://xpather.com/ получился следующий результат
**//div/div[@hidden]**
либо искомое противоположное
**//div/div[not(@hidden)]**

то есть

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div/div[not(@hidden)]')
```

ну теперь это будет выглядеть так:

```
//div/div[@class='line_champ' and not(@hidden)]
```

это работает, просто вам нужно выйти на данные узлы, видите. у меня два div'а стоят. вам следует поправить первый div, что бы попасть на искомые узлы.

вот мой пример xml

```
<div>
  <div class="line_chanp" >1</div>
  <div class="line_chanp" >2</div>
  <div class="line_chanp" hidden>3</div>
  <div class="NO_line_chanp" hidden>4</div>
  <div class="line_chanp" >5</div>
  <div class="NOline_chanp" >6</div>
  <div class="line_chanp" hidden>7</div>
  <div class="line_chanp" >8</div>
  <div class="line_chanp" >9</div>
  <div class="line_chanp" hidden>7</div>
</div>
```

возможно, окажется достаточным такое

```
//div[@class='line_champ' and not(@hidden)]
```

Comment: а конкретно в моем случае как будет выглядеть

Comment: приведите текст вашего xml, с картинки как-то трудно.

Comment: mav = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'line__champ')

Comment: browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='line__champ' and not(@hidden)") а как нужный класс line__champ туда впихнуть, так не работает

Comment: спс огромное. все работает как надо

Comment: если помогло, то добавьте "плюс" в "ответ полезен".